# Not creating json object

Tags: javascript, json, fabricjs

I'm playing around with fabric js, I can't seem to find a way too create/view a json object

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  width: 50, 
  height: 50, 
  fill: '#faa', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 300, 
  top: 300, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));

var w = canvas.toJSON();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8t4k1xkc/1/

I also tried JSON.stringify but got the converting circular structure to json error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote in your question works, you can turn it into a string with `JSON.stringify(w)` but also simply call `JSON.stringify(canvas)` (toJSON will be called for you by stringify).

The one on JSFiddle, does not, you are calling `canvas.toJSON(c)`, wrong, that way you are appending additional properties to the resulting JSON, in this case the same canvas (`c`, global variable automatically created by your browser for the html element with *id="c"*), thus the circular structure error.

See the [official documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON):

> **toJSON(propertiesToInclude)**
>
> *Returns JSON representation of canvas*
>
> Parameters:
>
> - *propertiesToInclude (Array)*:  Any properties that you might
>     want to additionally include in the output

Comment: Oops, thought I saved that fiddle.
Actually still isn't working, but I'm positive you're right. Must be something on my end.

Thanks mate